# Issues: Maven compiling jettison pom, "Could not transfer ... from/to central ..."

Tags: maven, maven-3

I've got a requirement to compile jettison-1.3.8 rather than use the version from the maven repo.  Not my choice...

I try to do this, and get:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
Downloading from central:     https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/felix/maven-bundle-plugin/1.0.0/maven-bundle-plugin-1.0.0.pom
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin is missing. @ line 54, column 15
[ERROR] Unresolveable build extension: Plugin org.apache.felix:maven-bundle-plugin:1.0.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.felix:maven-bundle-plugin:jar:1.0.0 @
[ERROR] Unknown packaging: bundle @ line 6, column 14 @
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR]   The project org.codehaus.jettison:jettison:1.3.8 (xxx/pom.xml) has 2 errors
[ERROR]     Unresolveable build extension: Plugin org.apache.felix:maven-bundle-plugin:1.0.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.felix:maven-bundle-plugin:jar:1.0.0: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.felix:maven-bundle-plugin:pom:1.0.0 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Received fatal alert: protocol_version -> [Help 2]
[ERROR]     Unknown packaging: bundle @ line 6, column 14
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
```

This is well out of my normal activities, so I'm not sure where I'm going wrong, except that it is NOT a proxy issue.

I'm running on a linux machine, so not windows issues, and from the command line - no graphical interface on this machine.

I have a fresh install of jdk 1.7 and a fresh install of maven-3.5.4.  I do not require a proxy on this machine.  (This is the answer that has turned up in nearly all my searches).

One thing I did find was an answer that pointed out the obvious - that I was having issues connecting to http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/

I attempted to validate this using wget, and received a 403 Forbidden error.  That seems weird.  I looked into this, and found something that suggested that some sites block wget due to incomplete headers.   So I ran that again with

```
wget -U 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070802 SeaMonkey/1.1.4' http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/
```

and was able to access the repo and download the index page.   So, again, NOT a proxy issue, I'm not having issues connecting to the central repo, but I'm wondering if I'm having issues retrieving the necessary plugins or dependencies because I'm being blocked by a similar issue to what wget showed.

I added the User-Agent field from above to my default wget configuration, just in case it was being used behind the scenes, but this did not help.

At this point, I'm completely out of ideas.  It looks like I should be able to connect to the central repo, get the plugin needed and move on, but that's not happening.

Comment: Please verify that the version of Maven that you're running is the one that you installed with `mvn --version`. FYI, I just cloned this project from https://github.com/codehaus/jettison and it built correctly "out of the box".

Comment: Not really sure how to preserve linefeeds in these comments.  

`$ mvn --version  

    Apache Maven 3.5.4 (1edded0938998edf8bf061f1ceb3cfdeccf443fe; 2018-06-17T13:33:14-05:00)  

    Maven home: /opt/apache-maven-3.5.4  

    Java version: 1.7.0_80, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_80/jre  

    Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: ISO-8859-1  

    OS name: "linux", version: "2.6.32-431.11.2.el6.x86_64", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"`

Comment: Make sure that your maven central repo configuration uses "https:" and not "http:"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to configure: `mvn -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2 clean package`. The reason is that Central has [upgraded to TLSv1.2 only](https://central.sonatype.org/articles/2018/May/04/discontinued-support-for-tlsv11-and-below/).